# asterisk call file not deleted

Tags: asterisk

I'm placing outgoing calls using Asterisk call files on Asterisk 1.8.  My call files are very simple and have no MaxRetries or RetryTime specified.  If a call succeeds, the corresponding callfile is deleted.

However, if the call fails for some reason, the callfile does not get deleted. Instead, it stays in the /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing directory, and has the following appended to it: "StartRetry: 1276 1 (1314160379)"

Why is that happening?  I'm expecting the file to be deleted immediately after the call, no matter what the resulting status of the call is.

Comment: I think might have to do with this, the dialplan seems to just stop:  http://serverfault.com/questions/304956/asterisk-system-function-not-working-in-dialplan

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have incorrect edit times on your call files.  Try setting AlwaysDelete to Yes.

> AlwaysDelete: Yes/No - If the file's modification time is in the future, the call file will not be deleted

Comment: Nope.  That didn't work.  Still get the StartRetry line and the file is not deleted.