# asterisk system function not working in dialplan

Tags: asterisk

After a call hangs up, I've setup several lines in my dialplan to execute system commands.  For instance, I have this in my dialplan:

```
exten => h,1,System(echo yo)
exten => h,n,System(echo yo)
exten => h,n,System(echo yo)
```

In my logs, all I'm seeing is one System command running:

```
[Aug 25 16:04:54] DEBUG[24437] pbx.c: Launching 'System'
[Aug 25 16:04:54] VERBOSE[24437] pbx.c:     -- Executing [h@fax-tx:4]     System("SIP/flowroute-00000014", "echo yo") in new stack
[Aug 25 16:04:54] DEBUG[778] devicestate.c: No provider found, checking channel drivers for SIP - flowroute
```

The rest are not running and the dialplan seems to just stop.  I don't see any additional errors occuring.  WTF is going on?

I'm running Asterisk 1.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

see other log output

h@fax-tx:4

mean h extension priority 4.
so it do somethign for 1-3, maybe  parts included by other contexts.